Include all finitely many versions of question in canvas r-exam
For a class activity, I would like to randomly assign "roles" to students and have them make a few character-specific choices ahead of class.
A simple example is as follows:
```{r, echo=TRUE, results="hide"}
i<-sample(1:5,1)
ids <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
price <- c("0.4","1","0.8","2","5")
```

Question
========
You go to supermarket `r ids[i]` and you observe that avocados cost USD `r price[i]` each. How many do you buy?


Meta-information
================
extype: num
exsolution: 0

When generate a canvas quiz with n=5, the samples (over i) are taken with replacement, so that I end up with a question pool that has multiples of the same ids but lacks others.
I understand where the issue is coming from (each call to the .Rmd file generates an independent draw of i), but I don't know how to circumvent it. I could set n=10,000 and hope that the law of large numbers already kicks in, but that seems like an overkill. (Also, it will make it a nightmare to interpret the results to recover the "average answer" of students with the same role.)
Is there some way of doing the randomization in the exams2canvas function, and then call the question file with an "input i" that runs from 1 to 5, so I have every version exactly once?
Update
I have written a helper function
write.versions <- function(file,dir=".",i.range) {
  for (i in i.range) {
    filei<-paste(dir,"/",tools::file_path_sans_ext(file),"-",i,".Rmd",sep="")
    write(paste("```{r, echo=TRUE, results=\"hide\"}\n i<-",i,"\n```",sep=""),
          file=filei)
    write(readLines(file),file=filei,append=TRUE)      
  }
}

It takes the filename (eg. test.Rmd) as input and then generates all variants of the file (just make sure you delete the i<-sample(1:5,1) line from the code above. Together with list(paste("test","-",1:5,".Rmd",sep="")), this then allows me to include it in the exams2xyz function. (Later addendum: Turns out the expar function would do that step more elegantly, as I have just discovered here.)
I can now generate a single exam that includes each variant exactly once, using, e.g.
exams2canvas(list(paste("test-",1:5,".Rmd",sep="")),nsamp=5)

since the nsamp parameter uses sampling without replacement when available. This allows me to upload it to canvas, where I then can manually pull all questions into the same question group to get the randomization.
It's still quite manual, of course, so if someone has a way to eliminate the need for that last step, that would be great!

To add some extra motivation for automating the last step: I think it would also be a function that is helpful more generally.
Often, exams are a combination of questions with true random draws (that should generated from scratch in each of the n exams) and 'hard coded' multiple choice questions where the instructor explicitly lists a finite number of variants (say 5) in the question list. These latter questions would be better included in a canvas question group of size 5, even when n is much larger.

With the current sampling, I could set n=20 and painstakingly write 5 individual true/false variants for Q1 of the exam, yet end up with one of them missing from the final question pool simply because the randomization was "unlucky". (And even when they are all present, some of them will be overrepresented in the draw of 20, which means students won't encounter all 5 versions with equal probability.)

Even if you make sure that your exercise is in the pool, then it still might not be used because, to the best of my knowledge, Canvas also samples with replacement.

Regarding hard-coded multiple-choice questions: I often recommend to create more than five alternatives and then set exshuffle: 5 which will lead to a greater variation of exercises presented to the participants (and not just permutations of a fixed set of alternatives). Note that this also supports more than one correct alternative in schoice exercises. See https://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/chatgpt/ for some example exercises (created with the help of ChatGPT).

My usual recommendation: In situations like this I typically recommend one of the following two strategies:

Don't worry about it. Just create a sufficiently large pool (100 should be good enough in the scenario you describe) and don't worry about the replications.

Use expar() to generate the versions with the fixed parameters (as you mention in your question). Here you could create the vector with all five versions via
tst <- sapply(1:5, function(ii) expar("test.Rmd", i = ii))

For more complicated combinations of parameters use the expargrid() function described in: Making deterministic versions of a parametrized question.


New alternative strategy: Because the issue of exact enumeration comes up repeatedly, I decided that I would add a new convenience function match_exams_iteration() in version 2.4-1 of the package (released to CRAN in July 2024). The function can query the current iteration among the n replications of an exercises. In your exercise this can be used to make sure to set i to 1 first, then 2, 3, 4, 5, and then again 1, 2, etc. The first line of your R chunk should be replaced by
i <- match_exams_iteration()
if(is.null(i)) i <- sample(1:5, 1) else i <- i - ((i - 1) %/% 5) * 5

The check for i being NULL make sure that the code also runs outside of exams2xyz() interfaces (and then resorts to sample()). The full test.Rmd file is provided below.
Ceterum censeo: In my experience it is better to invest the time into making more flexible exercises with more random variation than trying to make sure that relatively inflexible exercises are distributed evenly among participants. This is particularly true if you want to re-use exercises across exams/semesters.
Full example exercise:
```{r, echo=TRUE, results="hide"}
i <- match_exams_iteration()
if(is.null(i)) i <- sample(1:5, 1) else i <- i - ((i - 1) %/% 5) * 5
ids <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
price <- c("0.4","1","0.8","2","5")
```

Question
========
You go to supermarket `r ids[i]` and you observe that avocados cost USD `r price[i]` each.
How many do you buy?


Meta-information
================
extype: num
exsolution: 0


I understand the advice, and if the workflow is purely "instructor writes questions" - "students solve questions" - "autograde", then it makes total sense. However, as soon as the instructor wants to analyze the answers in any way, it is important that the answers are attached to the same LMS "item".

I don't understand what analyzing the items has to do with exactly fixing the number of replications. Or am I missing something here?

In a canvas quiz, the instructor can go to "Quiz statistics" and then sees how many students chose each of the available responses. (More detailed analysis is available by downloading the "student analysis" and "item analysis" csv files.) But both of these reporting methods are "per canvas item", so if canvas receives the same text as two separate questions, it will assign them two distinct "question ids", which makes analyzing the results much harder. One would have to manually "reassemble" the true totals from the excel files.

One approach might be to just include question titles to identify "same questions". One could then look up the corresponding (canvas) question ids from the excel file by that title, and group it that way. The main downside with doing it "ex-post" is that I believe question titles are displayed to students, which may be confusing if the title is something code-like such as "avocado-v3"...

I still think that this is a separate issue. The original question is about how to make sure to get each of a very finite set of scenarios exactly once. And with expar() and the new match_exams_iteration() you have two options how to achieve this. The question how to label these questions in Canvas so that they are recognized as the same or different items is separate from this, I think. So my feeling is that this question can be flagged as resolved.

Regarding the item labeling you should have various options to control this, see ?exams2qti12, e.g., stitle and ititle as well as sdescription etc. Maybe you can already tweak it in the way you want. Regarding the item analysis, I cannot say much because I haven't worked with this in Canvas (or other LMS). I typically download the statistics and roll my own analysis...
